# Windows vnc client that connects to Mac's multi user vnc server?

Tags: mac, osx-lion, vnc

So in Mac Lion the vnc server lets me do virtual desktops(multiple users logged in at the same time) just like Remote Desktop for windows does. This works great for mac clients, when I connect it prompts me to ask to share the screen or start a new virtual session with another login. However I haven't found a Windows client that will let me do anything other than the standard sharing of the logged in user. Does anyone know of a Windows vnc client that will allow me to login to a different user on the mac? In case some of you are used to the normal linux way of doing this, Mac does NOT share different users on different ports I.E. 5901 5902.... so you can't just vnc://192.168.x.x:5902 for a different user. I know I could use a different server to accomplish this, but I want to use the built in one.

Comment: Agree with you completely... it is simply unacceptable that no support for this exists, but not only that, there isn't really any indication or documentation I have found to give a clue that it isn't supported, resulting in lots of angry users trying to figure out why it won't work.